# The Proof of Minimizing Least Square

Tags: least-squares

We Know that To minimize the sum of error (objective Function)

$\ J = (y(t)-\theta (t) u(t))^2 $              (eq. 1)

is done by using least square :

$\theta (t) = \theta (t-1) +  \gamma  y(\theta u -y) $   (eq.2)

Where 
$u=input ;  $
$y=output;  $
$\theta=Gain Input;  $
$t=time;  $

But the question is  how to prove that eq.2 is minimizing the eq 1 respect to $\theta$?

and what the terms that shows $J$ is minimized ?

*Lets say all variables is scalar

Thanks before

Comment: You need to define your notation. What are $y$, $u$, $\theta$, $\gamma$, $n$, $t$? What is the choice variable in the minimization problem?

Comment: Thanks for the replay and corection, i've edit the equation

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit difficult to untangle this question. It should have a form where we start with a sequence on $m$ measurements of the form 
$$\left\{ x_{k}, y_{k} \right\}_{k=1}^{m}$$ 
with an input trial function 
$$
  y(x).
$$
which has parameters $a_{1}, a_{2}, \dots, a_{n}$. The method of least squares finds the vector $a$ which minimizes the total error
$$
  r^{2}(a) = \sum_{k=1}^{m} \left( y_{k} - y(x_{k}) \right)^{2}
$$
In fact, the least squares solution is defined as
$$ 
  a_{LS} = 
  \left\{
   a \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \colon
  r^{2}(a)
  \text{ is minimized}
  \right\}
$$
This sets up the following $n$ equations:
$$
\begin{align}
  \frac{\partial} {\partial a_{1}} r^{2}(a) & = 0 \\ 
  \frac{\partial} {\partial a_{2}} r^{2}(a) & = 0 \\ 
   \vdots  \\
  \frac{\partial} {\partial a_{n}} r^{2}(a) & = 0
\end{align}
$$

It would help to have your question nudged into something close to a format such as this.